# Oracle EntityFramework migration fails updating model_blob

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework-6

I'm working on an old project from 2016, using .NET Framework 4.5.1, Oracle and Entity Framework.

The model is very large, and after about 30 migrations it hits one that will not complete.  The Up() part of the migration works fine, but when updating the model I get:

> Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleException (0x80004005): ORA-08177: can't serialize access for this transaction
> ORA-06512: at line 152

If I run the migration with `-script`, I can see that it's unable to write the `model_blob` into the `__MigrationHistory` table.

Is there anything I can do to fix it?

Comment: Oracle is very sensitive to driver and database version so make sure you are using a driver version that is compatible with the database version.  Here is a link the may help : https://support.oracle.com/knowledge/Oracle%20E-Business%20Suite/1564007_1.html?force_isolation=true

Comment: That links to something to do with Oracle iStore.  I understand what you are saying about drivers and databases.  It's weird that it will do some of the migrations and then fail on this one.

Comment: What driver are you using?  Net or ODBC?  Check the connection string.  What version of Windows?  Looking at postings this morning with same error it was json issue.  I think the code is serializing the migration to json.  Error says "can't serialize access"

Comment: Oracle.ManagedDataAccess / Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework .NET drivers, V19.18.0 (last version supported by .NET framework), EF6 (6.2.0).  Windows 10.

Comment: Maybe you need to get some of these patches : https://support.oracle.com/knowledge/Oracle%20Cloud/19202204_9.html?force_isolation=true